# React-Native Metro Bundle does not appear on the page

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

Can't view metro bundle in chrome when I run app in React native

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

It has been removed. Read [here](https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206) for the reason.